# Restrict an InfoPath View to a Group

Tags: infopath, groups

I've been trying to figure this out and I'm running into a wall. I'm not too savvy in InfoPath but can figure some things out.

The scenario goes as below:

- I have a list called List A.
- As for users I have 2 groups. Within Group 1 I have users
  (Requestors) who's only duty is to Submit request using the List
  Form.
- Within Group 2 I have users (Admin) who's primary duty is to Approve,
  Edit, or Reject the submmission sent by the Requestors.
- In regards to the List Form, there are 4 Views. The Views are View 1,
  View 2, View 3 and View 4.

What I need to do is to restrict the Requestors in Group 1 to only see View 1 and no other Views because they don't have the rights to view additional information.

For example, a Requestor goes into List A, clicks New item and proceeds to fill out the form that is displayed in View 1. The user clicks Submit and the form closes. After the form is submitted, the Requestor cannot look at any other Views within List A except for View 1.

How do I restrict users in Group 1 to View 1 of the InfoPath form? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without code, using just InfoPath and the browser user interface:

- create a new SharePoint list "AuthorisedStaff". Add a Person field and a text field called Account to that list. Use InfoPath to customise the list form and create a rule to write the selected person's Account into the Account field. Add all people who should see the restricted section
- create a section in the InfoPath form of the main list that is hidden
- create a data connection to the AuthorisedStaff list
- Use a Form Load rule to extract the account name of the current user
- set the data connection query field to the current user's account name and query the data connection to AuthorisedStaff
- if the query returns an item the person is listed in AuthorisedStaff and you can unhide the hidden section. If the query returns nothing, the person is not listed and and the section remains hidden.

This is the big picture approach. There are lots and lots of details to take care of for each step above and if you are new to InfoPath you may feel a bit overwhelmed. Tackle one item at a time and ask a new question if you get stuck.